# Why can't I combine Google maps getCurrentPosition with place search API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to build a site that will enable the users to press a button or a link and it will show them stores near their location. I have used `getCurrentPosition` and place search services, which work well separately, but nothing happens when I combine the two. I think there is a way of combining them that I don't know how.

Below is the code I combined.

```
<head>
    <title>Churchtraker final</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content = "initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #map {
            height:100%;        
        }   
    </style>
    <script>
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initMap);
        } else {
            error('Sorry , Geolocation is not supported in your device');
        }
        var map;
        var infowindow;

        function initMap() {
            var latitude = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude);
            var longitude = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.longitude);
            var coords = { lat: latitude, lng: longitude };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                      center: coords,
                      zoom:15
                  });
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.nearbySearch({
                location: coords,
                radius:7000,
                type: ['store']
            }, callback);
        }

        function callback(results, status) {
            if(status === google.maps.places.placesServiceStatus.OK) {
                for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    createMarker(results[i]);
                }       
            }
        }

        function createMarker() {
            var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: place.geometry.location
             });
             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                 infowindow.setContent(place.name);
                 infowindow.open(map , this);
             });
        }    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=My_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geolocation service is asynchonous, you need to use the results in the callback function, when/where it is available.  You also need to put the argument in the callback function (in your case, should be initMap(position), but... you can't use that as the callback for the asynchronous load of the API as well.  One option is to call the geolocation code from the initMap function, and update the map if it succeeds.

```
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var coords = {
      lat: position.coords.latitude,
      lng: position.coords.longitude
    };

    map.setOptions({
      center: coords,
      zoom: 15
    });

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch({
      location: coords,
      radius: 7000,
      type: ['store']
    }, callback);
  }, errorHandler, geoLocOptions);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/x0r8vsp3/5/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var currentLocation;
var geoLocOptions = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var coords = {
      lat: position.coords.latitude,
      lng: position.coords.longitude
    };

    map.setOptions({
      center: coords,
      zoom: 15
    });

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch({
      location: coords,
      radius: 7000,
      type: ['store']
    }, callback);
  }, errorHandler, geoLocOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);

function errorHandler(err) {
  console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
};

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }

  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues:

1. you call `initMap` 2 times(remove the `callback`-parameter from the maps-API-src)
2. you must pass `position` as argument to `initMap`
3. the creation of `coords`/`latitude`/`longitude` is wrong
4. you must pass the `place` as argument to `createMarker`
5. `placesServiceStatus` must be `PlacesServiceStatus`

Fixed code:

```js
function initMap(position){
  var 
    center      = { lat: position.coords.latitude, 
                    lng: position.coords.longitude};
    map         = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
                    center: center,
                    zoom:11
                  }),
    callback    = function(results, status){
                    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK){
                      for (var i =0; i < results.length; i++){
                        createMarker(results[i]);
                      }
                    }
                  }

    createMarker= function(place){
                    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location,
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                      map: map,
                                      position: place.geometry.location
                                 });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click' , function (){
                      infowindow.setContent(place.name);
                      infowindow.open(map , this);
                    });
                  },
    infowindow  = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
    service     = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.nearbySearch({
        location: center,
        radius:7000,
        type: ['store']
    }, callback);

}


if (navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){initMap(position);});
}else{
    alert('Sorry , Geolocation is not supported in this environment');
}
```

Comment: Dr.Molle your method has given me a broader coding knowledge although it showed nothing, i guess it's because i mixed something with the html , or do you think still the code has an error?

Comment: There is no error in the code(I didn't post a code-snippet because as it seems geolocation has been disabled here for code-snippets) . Working fiddle based on the code above: https://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/e482ud6t/

Comment: Thanks Dr.Molle it also functions well , very well , now can you help me with the new problems i mentioned ?. The one for my computer (well in other devices such as phone) to show a wrong position , i.e showing famous city in my country instead of my exact location.

Comment: When your computer isn't connected via wi-fi the location will be based on your IP-address(if possible)....the result never may be very accurate. There is nothing you can do in this case(except you instruct the browser to use a particular location instead, e.g. by using a add-on like https://github.com/rldhont/geolocater )

Comment: and how can i specify a particular typeof place from the types parameter